# Postgresql: How do I join same table with where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have one table `statistic`. The table has `step_index`, for example `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. I need make query add `week2` and `total_request2` where week is `37` and join self table with same `step_index`.

Example:

```
step_index|type    |year|week|total_request|
----------+--------+----+----+-------------+
         1|Blasting|2021|  38|            1|
         2|Blasting|2021|  38|            1|
         3|Blasting|2021|  38|            1|
         4|Blasting|2021|  38|            1|
         1|Blasting|2021|  37|            6|
         2|Blasting|2021|  37|            6|
         3|Blasting|2021|  37|            6|
         4|Blasting|2021|  37|            6|
```

The result should be:

```
step_index|type    |year|week|total_request|week2|total_request2|
----------+--------+----+----+-------------+-----+--------------+
         1|Blasting|2021|  38|            1|   37|             6|
         2|Blasting|2021|  38|            1|   37|             6|
         3|Blasting|2021|  38|            1|   37|             6|
         4|Blasting|2021|  38|            1|   37|             6|
```

I tried inner join and with clause, but not result `week2` and `total_request2`.

Comment: If there is a third week, 39th, then you expect week3 and total_request3 ?

Comment: no, I'm expecting week 38 and 37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 WITH CTE(STEP_INDEX,TYPE,YEAR,WEEK,TOTAL_REQUEST) AS
  (
    SELECT 1,'BLASTING',2021,38,1  UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2,'BLASTING',2021,38,1  UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3,'BLASTING',2021,38,1  UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4,'BLASTING',2021,38,1  UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1,'BLASTING',2021,37,6  UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2,'BLASTING',2021,37,6  UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'BLASTING',2021,37,6  UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'BLASTING',2021,37,6  
  )

 SELECT C.STEP_INDEX,C.TYPE,C.YEAR,C.WEEK,C.TOTAL_REQUEST,
   X.WEEK AS WEEK_2,X.TOTAL_REQUEST AS TOTAL_REQUEST_2
  FROM CTE AS C
 LEFT JOIN LATERAL
  (
     SELECT C2.STEP_INDEX,C2.TYPE,C2.YEAR,C2.WEEK,C2.TOTAL_REQUEST
     FROM CTE AS C2
      WHERE C.STEP_INDEX=C2.STEP_INDEX AND C.WEEK-1=C2.WEEK AND C.YEAR=C2.YEAR
  )X ON TRUE
  WHERE C.YEAR=2021 AND C.WEEK=38
```

Based on your sample data

Answer (score 0):

Based off what you provided, here is my best guess of what you want.
If you can clarify the primary keys and some more specific information about what you're looking for, I can revise my query to be better.

```
select s.step_index
,s.type
,s.year
,s.week
,s.total_request
,s2.week
,s2.total_request2
from statistic s
,statistic s2
where s2.week = 37
and s2.step_index = s.step_index
and s.week = 38
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as an explicit `JOIN`.  The correct syntax would be:

```
select s.step_index, s.type, s.year, s.week, s.total_request,
       s2.week as week2, s2.total_request as total_request2
from statistic s join
     statistic s2
     on s2.year = s.year and
        s2.step_index = s.step_index and
        s2.week = 37 and
        s.week = 38
```